# Управление расширением Firefox в selenium

Tags: python, selenium, firefox, addons

Установил расширение FoxyProxy для Firefox с помощью Selenium, вот только как теперь добавлять от selenium'a прокси ? Как вообще можно управлять расширениями в selenium ?

Answer (score 0):

Спустя день поисков я понял что через selenium управлять управлениями нельзя, либо не описано в общем доступе. Принципиально мне все равно как менять айпи, так что можно использовать selenium-wire:

```
from seleniumwire import webdriver
options = {
'proxy': {
    'http': 'http://username:password@host:port',
    'https': 'https://username:password@host:port',
    'no_proxy': 'localhost,127.0.0.1,dev_server:8080'
    }
}
driver = webdriver.Firefox(seleniumwire_options=options)
```

Либо же для управления можно попробовать полазить в sqlite базу этого расширения в профиле пользователя, настройки прокси там хранятся в бинарном виде